# Set the parameter values retreved from database in Arcgis script tool in toolbox using python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool

I am now thinking a function to allow user to modify his information stored in the database. To do this, I developed 2 script tools in ArcGIS(10.2), One is the ask user to input his ID, the other one is to retrieve the data from database and allow user update the information before update it in database. The 2 tools are shown below in sequence.

[image]

[image]

I have 3 questions:

1. How to set the parameter values in the script tool in toolbox, I mean when open the tool, all the existing value retrieved from database has already displayed in the tool. I tried to search the solution but haven’t got a useful solution.
2. When I tried to use the first tool to call the second tool, is it possible to close the first one? It may look messy to the user.
3. Since the user ID is unique and cannot be modified, how to prevent this parameter from editing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Adding_a_script_tool/00150000001r000000/ it describes setting up a tool script.

To get the parameters from the tool use `sys.argv[]` http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv where `sys.argv[1]` is the first parameter. Python doesn't have variable types so be careful you get them in the right order or the error might only show up much later.

Comment: I just read something in the [ArcGIS Pro Help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/accessing-parameters-in-a-script-tool.htm) that may interest you because I've noticed that you always use `sys.argv[]` when I always use `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()`.  I've always thought it was six of one and half a dozen of the other but the help says "`sys.argv` has limitations on the number of characters it can accept. `GetParameterAsText` has no character limit. For this reason alone, it is recommended that you use `GetParameterAsText`."